# Multiprocessing - setting the pool size in a portable manner

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

When creating a multiprocessing.Pool instance with no argument, it is my understanding that the pool size will be assigned the value of os.cpu_count()

On my machine os.cpu_count() == 20

Also:-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool() as pool:
  print(len(pool.__dict__['_pool']))
```

...gives me a value of 20

But here's the problem (if indeed it is a problem). My CPU is a Xeon W-2150B. Thus it is a single CPU with 10 cores where each core is capable of handling 2 concurrent threads (hyper-threading). And so the value of 20 seems to be the number of concurrent threads that the CPU can handle.

However, it seems to me that one wouldn't want to create a pool size that's going to "use up" the CPU's capabilities in its entirety because any other processes running on the same machine would suffer degradation.

So, my thinking is that the pool size should be limited to (number_of_cores - 1)

One way of doing this would be as follows:-

```
import psutil
from multiprocessing import Pool

maxWorkers = max(2, psutil.cpu_count(logical=False) - 1)
with Pool(maxWorkers) as pool:
    print(len(pool.__dict__['_pool']))
```

...gives a value of 9 which I think is much more reasonable and, potentially, more portable.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Your question assumes that your operating system is not capable of scheduling tasks properly.

Comment: If the processes you intend to run in the pool are realtime processes that can't be scheduled, then you should leave some cpu's available for the OS if you want it to respond. If your processes priority is regular then the OS we schedule them and whenever you have a task that needs to run, the OS will interrupt processes in the pool and reschedule them

Comment: Regarding the hyper threading - this is a CPU feature that maximizes the CPU's capabilities, why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application.

When you create a `Pool` in size `n`, `n` empty processes are created. Those processes almost doesn't consume CPU until a task is applied to them.

So another approach can be to set the `Pool` with maximum size and limit the number of running processes with another logic - hold a queue for incoming tasks, and apply them to the pool as long as you don't reach a limit of parallelly running processes.

This approach might be useful if you might want to increase the number of running processes in runtime. Decreasing the number of processes needs more logic.

Notice that even after you apply a task to a process in the pool, the OS still have control over it, so it can be scheduled and interrupted by the OS according to its priority.

Comment: I don't see the benefits of using a queue when the number of concurrent processes can be effectively limited by the Pool class's constructor

Comment: @DarkKnight If you want to increase the number of running processes in runtime, that's one way to do that, otherwise you have to close the pool (wait for no processes to run) and open a new one